# Trying to use ggplot with data who came from RposrgreSQL

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the attached command in R

```
> plot_events <-ggplot(Data1,aes(x=factor(date),y=users,fill=users))
```

but i received the attached error 
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class PostgreSQLResult

Data1 created through the attached script

```
library("RPostgreSQL", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library")
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
conn <-dbConnect(drv,host='mm-stats-1.ctea4hmr4vlw.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',port='xxx',dbname='yyy',user='zzz',password='Erez1234')
dbListConnections(drv)
Data1 <-dbSendQuery(conn,"select family,date(ts),count(*),count(distinct uid)as Users from mr_session_log group by family,date(ts) order by date(ts)")
fetch(Data1,n=-1)
```

I'm new in R and i belive it's a very simple problem so thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot2 only accepts objects of class `data.frame` as input, apparently your object is of a different data type. You can always check the data type of an object with:

```
class(data_object)
str(data_object)
```

Probably you can coerce the object to `data.frame` with

```
Data1_df <- as.data.frame(Data1)
```

Comment: thanks, there is a way that i can create the vector directly as data_frame when i'm uploading data from my PostgreSQL